# HTML <option> with showing text but a blank value

Tags: html, jquery-select2, html-select

I want to use a select with an option that sends a blank value (empty string) when the form is submitted, but I still want the option to show text in the select. Using this doesn't work, as it shows no text for the third option:

```
<select name='scope' id='scope'>
  <option value="wz:964" selected>Scope A</option>
  <option value="sz:34218">Scope B</option>
  <option value="">Scope C</option>
</select>
```

Though this works in plain HTML, I am using Select2 3.5.4, and it doesn't work after processing, since is replaces the third option with `<option value=""></option>`

Comment: Maybe instead of an empty string, just include a special character like an underscore or something? <option value="_">

Comment: Put a value to the position you want to show in **Select2** and then, validation-posting time, you could detect which index you want empty and do empty it (**index** is the property who shows the position of an option in a drop-down list). Same logic could be applied detecting which selection the user did. Detecting the **selected** property user posted you could intercept the posting and blank value before it (if he selected the option you want blank).

Answer (score 0):

I run the following sample code in local

**Sample Code:**

```
<head>
    <link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery("#example").select2(); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="post">
    <select id="example" multiple="multiple" name="example[]" style="width: 300px">
        <option value="wz:964">Scope A</option>
        <option value="sz:34218">Scope B</option>
        <option value="&nbsp;">Scope C</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<?php

print_r($_REQUEST);
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Note:**
Use the "&nbsp;" instead of "".

Hope it will helpful.